# NameError uninitialized constant in ruby on rails index method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a new controller to try to handle .csv imports for a web application I am writing for my senior project. I used example code and tutorials to get to this and I am getting a NameError when I run it, which is occuring inside of my index method, so the 'new' method must be fine because it gets past that one. The index method in my other controller works fine so this one has stumped me pretty good. 
[Picture of error message on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlY1G.png)
I have also tried a ton of combinations of capitals and underscores and what not but may have missed the right one, my controller is below

```
class PlantDataController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @plantdata = PlantData.new
  end

  def index
    @plantdata = PlantData.all
  end

  def import
    PlantData.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Plant Data imported."
  end
end

class PlantDatum < ApplicationRecord
require 'csv'

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

      plant_data_hash = row.to_hash # exclude the price field
      plant_data = Plant_data.where(id: plant_data_hash["id"])

      if plant_data.count == 1
        plant_data.first.update_attributes(plant_data_hash)
      else
        Product.create!(plant_data_hash)
      end # end if !product.nil?
    end # end CSV.foreach
  end # end self.import(file)
end # end class
```

It is expected that the page opens and does not give me an error message on my server. I want to import data from plants I am keeping using sensors and automatic watering and lighting to try to compare that to plants I am keeping normally with hand watering and just getting natural light.

Comment: Please include error backtrace to your question

Comment: From that image, your method is not indented properly. Can you post your model, and routes code here too.
And also did you subclass any of controllers or models in question? To rephrase the last question, how does your folder structure looks like for controller and model?

Comment: Does `PlantData` exist? Is it in the expected directory (models or whatever it is in Rails)? Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: `class PlantDatum` ?  
`Plant_data.where(id: plant_data_hash["id"])`?

Comment: okay okay I am sorry this is my first time using the forum. The model that was generated from migrating "Plant Data" was called "Plant_datum" which was kind of confusing to me and might be causing the problem. I am unsure though because none of the models are called "Plant_Data" but I know that the migration occurred properly. I might just need to rename the controller to "PlantDatum"?

Comment: Well, you don't have class with such name.

Comment: "I might just need to rename the controller to "PlantDatum"" - controller is likely just fine. It's the model that can't be found.

Comment: In general you'll only want to use classes that actually exist, and in Rails, convention rules: either stick with the defaults, or align everything.

Comment: Alright so turned out the name of the model was the problem. I just found it confusing because that was the first time a migration did not generate the name for the model that I had put in as the name of the migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
class PlantDatum < ApplicationRecord
```

should be

```rb
class PlantData < ApplicationRecord
```

Inside that model, fix this line in import method

```rb
plant_data = Plant_data.where(id: plant_data_hash["id"])
```

to look like this

```rb
plant_data = PlantData.where(id: plant_data_hash["id"])
```